# Python Bytecode + LOAD_NAME by value or by name?

Tags: python, bytecode, call-by-value, callbyname

I'm a french CS teacher in highschool. We are investigating the execution of Bytecode on the Python Virtual Machine. We ended up with a naïve question : after a `LOAD_NAME 0` (command at adress 8 of the bytecode)  is executed, what's on Top of the Stack, the symbol `x` ? or the value pointed by `x` ? (238 here).

Next follows the disassembled bytecode

```
CONSTS (238, 1512, None)
NAMES ('x', 'y', 'm')
VARNAMES ()
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (238)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (1512)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (y)
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
             12 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20
             16 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             18 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 22)
        >>   20 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
        >>   22 STORE_NAME               2 (m)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

obtained with

```
import dis

prog = compile('x=238;y=1512;m=x if (x>y) else y;', '<string>', 'exec')
print(f"CONSTS {prog.co_consts}")
print(f"NAMES {prog.co_names}")
print(f"VARNAMES {prog.co_varnames}")
dis.dis(prog)
```

I guess `inspect` module allows to trace the TOS, but I did not take the time to crawl through its doc yet, so If someone can share knowledge We are interested. Thx in advance

Comment: It's the value that gets pushed on the stack.  If the bytecode needed to push the variable name instead for some reason, that would be a LOAD_CONST of a string.

Comment: Thx ! Do you know a simple way to inspect the TOS ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to examine the evaluation stack during runtime - the various stack-related functions in `inspect` are all talking about the function call stack instead.  One alternative would be to insert bytecode at the point of interest to display the TOS - DUP_TOP followed by PRINT_EXPR, perhaps.  (A module such as `byteplay` makes this modification much less painful than it would otherwise be.)

Comment: I'll try that. Thx for all !

Comment: LOAD_NAME number is equivalent to getting the module's codeobject's co_varnames[numer], and then pushing it to the stack. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html